# lightbox not working correctly

Tags: javascript, lightbox

I have a problem in lightbox. This is the link when i clicked login form appears.

```
<a href="index.php?g=login.html" title="Login Form"
 rel="gb_page_center[425, 220,login.html]">Login</a>
```

When I click the link before page loads, page opens in new window. light box isn't working correctly. I need to block this link utill lightbox loads.

How can I do this in javascript?

click the top corner link **login**

Link: http://www.clubforeducation.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try adding some attribute like onclick='return false;' ?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to include your lightbox javascript code at the bottom of the page.
Or hide all your images initially while page is loading; once page is loaded, you can show all links again with something like below:

```
window.onload = function()
{
  // note: using jquery here
  $("a.lightboxlinks").css('display':'inline');
};
```